# Installing mongoose server on windows from linux using winexe

Tags: http, windows-services, mongoose-web-server, winexe

I want to start mongoose http server as service on the windows machine from the linux host.

For executing command on windows machine remotely from the linux machine, winexe tool is there. 
Admin share being enabled on the windows side, we can run winexe command from linux. Winexe uploads 
winexesvc service on the windows machine which gives access to linux machine.

As there are two files, service.c and winexesvc.c for service service skeleton and routine to enable the access respectively in winexe source code. (winexe/source4/winexe/winexesvc/ )

Now i want mongoose server get installed as service on remote machine. For that I have renamed 
main.c file in mongoose source code as service.c as it has skeleton for service

and 
mongoose.c as winexesvc.c as it contains core logic of http server. But when i tried running updated 
winexe from linux, service for running mongoose server uploaded in [admin share of] windows machine as required.
But service doesn't start. After timeout, it gives error

**error 1053: service did not respond to start or control request in timely fashion.**

I have tried to make changes in timeout by increasing it, but it still exist.
And one more thing, whenever i run same uploaded file (service for running mongoose server ) as application, it runs fine as http server serving the client.

Please tell me if you have any idea regarding how to solve this issue .
Thanks in advance.